# aws s3 upload silent errors

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've been uploading a couple thousand files to s3. They're small-ish pdf files, about 40k in size.

I wrote a python script to generate a pdf file, upload to s3, then delete the original. I've found that about 1 in 4 uploads just don't happen.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(<local-file>, <bucket-name>, <remote-path>)
```

I'm looking at my logs, and I don't see any errors, no exceptions were thrown. I look at the AWS dashboard, no alarms went off.

Is there some kind of upload command with a more verbose output to detect failed uploads?

Comment: you can use `aws s3 cp local_folder s3://bucket_name/` to copy all local files to s3 or `aws s3 sync`. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html

Comment: The boto3 functions would throw an error if one occurred, so either your code is swallowing the errors or the code is not actually doing what you think it's doing. Is it possible that either the 'missing' uploads never actually happened, or that you are looking in the wrong place in S3 to see the files after upload, or that you haven't waited long enough to list the objects (S3 list is eventually consistent after a put)?

Comment: Did you find a solution to that problem?